# How to use calc function inside of min function as value of width property?

Tags: css

I am trying to specify the value of the width property. To make width responsive I am using the `min` function instead of the media query.

For the bigger screen, I want the width to restrict to `900px` and for smaller screens, I want with to be `100%-20px`

I am trying to implement it using `width: min(calc(100% - 20px),900px);` but it does not work. Please guide me.

Comment: your code works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/638njevx/

Answer (score 4):

You over complicating the issue. The way it is solved is to use following CSS:

```css
element {
  width: calc(100% - 20px);
  max-width: 900px;
}
```

it calcs the width as `100% -20px` but will limit it to `900px`. This means, if the `100% -20px` would be larger than `900px` then it will stay at `900px`.